# How can you tell when a participle is being used as an adjective?

Tags: participles

How can you tell when a participle is being used as an adjective?

I feel completely lost trying to guess. Just as a completely arbitrary example

- For every **dedicated** scientist patiently **recording** atmospheric
  pressure and wind speed while **shivering** at high altitudes, there is a
  carnival barker with a bevy of pretty girls **willing** to dangle from a
  basket or parachute down to earth.