# Is "were scattered" a construction of passive voice or a simple past tense?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I am doing a study on the verbal forms "Simple Past". I have doubts with the construction "were scattered", because I do not know if it is the verb *to be* conjugated in Simple Past and followed by an adjective, or it is a Passive Construction, which I would therefore exclude from my study.

Therefore, is the verb that I have highlighted in bold written as part of a passive construction? Why? Or why not?

> ...One, with his chin propped on his knees, stared at nothing, in an intolerable and appalling manner: his brother phantom rested its forehead, as if overcome with a great weariness; and all about others **were scattered** in every pose of contorted collapse, as in some picture of a massacre or a pestilence.

from *Heart of Darkness*, by Joseph Conrad.

Comment: You are mistaken to think that there is a "passive voice" in English. There is a Passive Construction, which applies to clauses, and that could be what _were scattered_ is part of. However, there is also a Perfect Passive Participle, a form of the verb that is used in the Passive Construction, but also often appears as an adjective, as in _Scattered around the floor I found the missing Legos_, and that's another possibility for _were scattered_ in this sentence. You can't tell which construction is used in that sentence. But it doesn't matter, because there's no difference in meaning.

Comment: Perhaps an easier-to-grasp pair of examples showing this infamous ambiguity is 'The kitchen window was broken'. (a) The kitchen window was broken by a falling tile. (b) The kitchen window was broken, they found on arriving at the house, and they knew they had been burgled.

Comment: @user9825893y50932: the selected answer to that question is full of misstatements and revisions, demonstrating rather clearly that there is no "passive voice" in English, but rather a variety of Passive constructions and verb forms, which do not amount to a "Voice", but rather a confusing panoply of terminology. Technically speaking, English verbs have no voices, no moods, no aspects, and only two tenses. Everything else is done by constructions, most using auxiliary verbs; certainly the Passive Construction requires an auxiliary _be_.

Comment: Related: [“The cake was baked.” Is “baked” a past participle or predicate adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440541)

Comment: @Scott Duplicate comments?

Comment: @Araucaria: Sometimes a comment is just a comment.  sumelic’s comment was just a comment.  The one with my name attached to it was auto-generated by the system when I voted to close. Related: [Custom close reason is processed as a comment](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7436/150988).

Comment: @JohnLawler Yet (1) this site maintains a passive-voice tag; (2) the multiple times that the accepted answer was revised speaks as to the difficulty of coming up with a schema for the asked question, as it was asked, (3) that it was accepted means nothing more than that it was "helpful" to the user (OP), not that it correctly articulated someone else's POV.

Comment: In the context in which the passage occurs, were the "others" scattered by an agent other than themselves? Was there an "agent" that scattered them? If so, its a passive construction. Or were they just lying around, in a "scattered" manner? If so, we don't know if it is a passive construction? And in English we cannot always know this. That is the answer.

Comment: Don't draw any conclusions based on the tag system; imo it's totally inconsistent and of no real value.  The reason why the question is hard to ask is because it's got some untrue presuppositions which make an answer impossible. For instance, the idea that two words in one sentence **must** "be .. a passive construction or not". That's not a fact, that's an analysis based on definition, and both the definition and the analysis are incorrect. There aren't as many sharp edges in syntax as some seem to believe.

Comment: @JohnLawler If you don't like the selected answer, write one you like. Or search for one that you like. That is how SE works.

Answer (score 3):

The passive and simple past constructions in English are not exclusive. Clauses are considered to be *simple* past when there is one past tense verb and the clause lacks any marking for the continuous or the perfect aspects. The continuous is marked by the presence of the auxiliary *BE* and a gerund-participle form of the following verb (the *-ing* form). The perfect aspect is marked by the presence of the auxiliary *HAVE* plus a so-called past participle form of the lexical verb:

- The elephants **ate** the donuts. (past simple)
- The elephants **were eating** the donuts. (past continuous)
- The elephants **had eaten** the donuts. (past perfect)

Note that all three of the sentences above use past tense verbs, and that they only have one tensed verb per clause.

We can construct passive versions of any of the sentences above, and they will retain their tense and aspect labels. To do this we move *the donuts* to the Subject position and insert the passive auxiliary *BE* followed by a past participle form of *ATE*. Note that the passive auxiliary *BE* always comes last in the series of auxiliary verbs:

- The donuts **were eaten**. (past simple)
- The donuts **were being eaten**. (past continuous)
- The donuts **had been eaten**. (past perfect)

These three clauses all retain the necessary features for them to be labeled as past and then simple, continuous or perfect respectively.

**The Original Poster's example**

> others were scattered in every pose of contorted collapse

How we analyse this clause depends on whether we view the word *scattered* as an instantiation of the verb or the adjective. The syntactic evidence here is largely inconclusive - although the meaning, given the surrounding paragraph, would suggest that it is an adjective (in other words, there is a reading where *scattered* indicates would indicate an event not a state, but given the surrounding description, this is not a likely reading). Either way, whether the verb *scattered* is a verb or an adjective , the clause is a past simple construction. It has one past tense verb, the verb *were*, and it lacks the necessary features to be considered either continuous or perfect. If the verb *scattered* is an adjective, then we would regard the clause as active. If it is a past participle form of a verb, then we would consider the clause as passive.

Comment: I interpret _scattered_ as an adjective here.  For it to be a passive, it should theoretically be possible to replace _were_ with _got_; e.g., _The window was / got broken_. But, "_all about others got scattered in every pose of contorted collapse_" does not work for me in the context of the passage. If, on the other hand, the past perfect is used, then we clearly have a passive construction and the tenses in the passage maintain consistency: "_all about others had been scattered in every pose of contorted collapse_".

Comment: @Shoe I agree in in terms of the semantics it's almost definitely an adjective, although there's no syntactic way of demonstrating this. However, I've edited the post. Thanks.