# Ambiguity in the nature of the participle: an adjective, a verb or a non-finite participle clause

Tags: passive-voice, participial-phrases, deverbal-adjectives, nonfinite-clause-complementation

Is there ay test to differentiate between an adjective phrase, a participle clause and a verb phrase in the passive? I know they all function as modifiers to an NP. In the following examples I am a bit perplexed as to the nature of the parenthesized constituents:

**I heard that he [was beaten] to death**

I am confused in regards to the nature of "beaten" here: is it an adjective phrase or just a verb in the passive (because it accepts a -by phrase); I do not believe that it is a participle clause because it is not reduced

**The protests [triggered by his death] have ceased**

This is clearly a participle clause because it is reduced and it functions as a modifier to the NP [protests].If this is the case,  is it correct to consider the PP (by his death) here as a verb complement to the verb "trigger" ?

**I didn't know that she was [abandoned]**

I know that the constituent is not a participle clause(because it is preceded by an auxiliary, and participle clauses are always reduced), meaning it is either a verb in the passive (because it accepts a -by phrase) or an adjective phrase that functions as a subject complement to (she).

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions on the difference (or similarity) between adjectives and past participles, e.g. [this one on "stapled"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page).

Comment: Participles are just participles. In the original Parts of Speech, "participium" was its own part of speech (and adjectives were not, since the Romans considered them simply nouns with no intrinsic genders). We consider participles simply verbs without ordinary inflections.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you tell when a participle is being used as an adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327121/how-can-you-tell-when-a-participle-is-being-used-as-an-adjective) (merged with [verb or adjective in 
 'the blue page is stapled to the red page](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page)). See also [ed endings: adjective or past participle...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507404/ed-endings-adjective-or-past-participle-in-perfect-tenses-passive-voice-and-af).